# Why is the .NET Colors class not static?

Tags: c#, .net

I was browsing the colors class's source in reflector and it's just a sealed class. But all members are static. So why would anyone create a copy of the Colors class?

It lies inside:

```
System.Windows.Media.Colors
```

Comment: The members are all static so you do not need to instantiate a copy and further more you can't since the constructor is not available through conventional means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A static class is just a sealed **abstract** class with <s>private constructor</s> no constructors (as in, no constructors at any accessibility level, not even ones generated by the compiler) [fixed per Eric's comment]. The C# keyword `static` is simply a shorthand for that, and also forces you to make all members static, but for API clients it's exact same thing.

Given that work on WPF (then Avalon) began before .NET 2.0 was released, it could be that this particular class was written before `static class` appeared. Or perhaps the author was simply unaware of that language feature.

Comment: Your first paragraph is not correct. A static class is *not* implemented as a sealed class with a private constructor. Rather, a static class is a *sealed abstract class with no constructors*.

Comment: As far as I know, a static class can have a private default constructor (parameterless) that can initialize any static members if needed and CLR guarantees to call it once per AppDomain before any member or the type itself is referenced.

Comment: To clear up a potential misunderstanding: Chansik Im is referring to the *static constructor* (.cctor), Eric Lippert is referring only to *instance constructors* (.ctor).

Comment: There are differences in the way the IL is formed. You cannot instantiate a new static class because of the `abstract` modifier. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For me, `Colors.AliceBlue` and `Colors.AntiqueWhite` (the first and the second static property of Colors class :)) should be difference instances of Color objects instead of different types.

`public static Color AliceBlue {get;}`

Please note that a static class is a sealed class that contains only static members and *cannot be instantiated using the **new** keyword* as it can only have a private default constructor (at least in C#).

Imagine you are creating an API that takes Color as an argument, what will it look like if the Color is a static class?

One can argue that different colors should be different types (arguably static as well) instead of different instances of the Color class.  Even with this case, Color should not be a static class because you want to have a base Color class for individual Color classes and making the base Color class static automatically makes it sealed.

One may still want to argue that Color should be a namespace and individual colors should be static classes.  I will simply ask them to imagine what the API will look like again :)

Comment: He's not talking about `Color` class (which is also there, and isn't static). He's talking about `Colors` class, which exists solely to provide members like `Red` and `Green` - it's a separate class in WPF.

Comment: Oh... I see. Thanks for your comment. I got confused by taking the original question literally. In this case, I agree that Colors could have been a static class.

Answer (score 1):

Because a `sealed` class with all static members and private constructor constitutes certain performance enhancements because of the way the `IL` is formed for the use of the `static` class versus the `sealed` class, in-fact the static class gets the `abstract` modifier in IL to prevent new from being called where as the `sealed` class does not.

See.. [This post on msdn social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/csharplanguage/thread/7f0b56ca-fc61-4b64-ae31-3581398996e8)